# String Assignment -Clarification

Tags: c#, string, variable-assignment

When i declare

```
string x = new string(new char[0]);
```

It works fine.My question is what value will be assigned to x ?

when i check

```
Console.WriteLine(x.CompareTo(null)==0);,it returns false.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you assign new char[0], your string is not null.  It is empty.

you could do:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Answer (score 5):

`x` will be an empty string, the same as `x = ""`.

`null` and `""` are two distinct string values.  In particular, `null` is a null reference, so you cannot call any instance members on it.  Therefore, if `x` is null, `x.Length` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

By contrast, `""` (or `String.Empty`) is an ordinary string that happens to contain 0 characters.  Its instance members will work fine, and `"".Length` is equal to 0.

To check whether a string is `null` or empty, call (surprise) [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You've picked an interesting case here, because on .NET it violates the principle of least surprise. Every time you execute

```
string x = new string(new char[0]);
```

you will get a reference to the *same* string.

(EDIT: Just to be very clear about this - it's a non-null reference. It refers to a string just as it would if you used any other form of the constructor, or used a string literal.)

I'm sure it *used* to refer to a different string to "", but now it appears to be the same one:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object x = new string(new char[0]);
        object y = new string(new char[0]);
        object z = "";
        Console.WriteLine(x == y); // True
        Console.WriteLine(x == z); // True
    }
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this is the *only* case where calling `new` for a class can return a reference to an existing object.

Comment: While this is an interesting point, it's got nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Slaks: I don't see how it has nothing to do with the question. In particular, it's a reference to a string, so it's non-null. I think the fact that you get the same reference every time is *entirely* relevant to the question.

Comment: Is this equivalent to saying two strings instantiated as above will have the same address?

Comment: @Skeet: I meant that it doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: @SLaks: In what way? The question is "what value will be assigned to x" and the answer is "a reference to a string - the same (non-null) reference every time you execute the line". How does that not answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

The string is isn't null, it's empty.

```
Console.WriteLine(x.CompareTo(String.Empty)==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.CompareTo(string.Empty) == 0);
```